# Where is Ribet, Russia-Poland?

Tags: poland, russia

Grandmother Emma Kliner was born in Ribet, Russia-Poland in 1892 according to her naturalization papers.

Passenger list in 1909 says Rybitwy as best as i can read it.

Trying to find this town, and relatives- family name of 
Klenner or Kliner or Klinger
mother is Elizabeth or Louisa
father is Frederick or Ferdinand

in later documents she calls herself German
other documents mention Belarus, Thorn, Plock

Comment: Could it be https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rybice ?

Comment: @GeorgeGaál Nope, that place was Germany in 1892.

Comment: @Bregalad sorry, it's my mistake

Answer (score 4):

There are [a number of possibilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rybitwy) but [Georgenburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rybitwy,_Kuyavian-Pomeranian_Voivodeship) (in German):

> Rybitwy is a village in the administrative district of Gmina Pakość, within Inowrocław County, Kuyavian-Pomeranian Voivodeship, in north-central Poland.

seems one of the most likely as Plock and [Toruń](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toru%C5%84) (Thorn in German) are a couple of the nearest densely populated areas with names that are less challenging to those who are not Polish.

This largely disregards the Belarus reference.

Another possibility is [Rybitwy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rybitwy,_Lublin_Voivodeship) the:

> village in the administrative district of Gmina Józefów nad Wisłą, within Opole Lubelskie County, Lublin Voivodeship, in eastern Poland.

which is about 50 miles from another Toruń. Both however are not far from (the much bigger) Lublin and that has a name that also translates easily – but a location a long way from Plock.

[image]

PS Rybitwy is Polish for tern.

Comment: Thank you for the insights. family legend tells that Ribet was near a river that flooded every year.  I also do not know gramma's religion.